# Post method not allowed drf

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

Here is the view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def createProduct(request):
    user = request.user
    product = Product.objects.create(
        user=user,
        name='Sample Name',
        price=0,
        brand='Sample Brand',
        countInStock=0,
        category='Sample category',
        description='',
    )
    product.save()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('api/products/create/', product_views.createProduct, name='create-product'),


]
```

Here is the frontend action

```
export const createProduct = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/products/create/',{}, config);

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

It's showing  "detail": "Method "POST" not allowed." . Seems like everything is fine to me. waiting to hear your opinions.

If I use get method then it shows creating instance error. I tried everything in my knowledge.

Comment: Test it without `@permission_classes` - same result ?

Comment: yeah the result is same.

Comment: Method Not Allowed: /api/products/create/
[01/Jul/2021 12:14:29] "POST /api/products/create/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had the same problem try this -
I assume you are have multiple urls . move your create url above the get url.